# Random password generator sh script

Tags: sh, macos

Yesterday, I was bored and decided to write a random password generator. At first it used numerous temporary files, changed that by using arrays.

This was written on OS X and should work on Linux with minor tweaks (at least change all gshuf to shuf).

Example use:

> ```
> $ pw -c 3 -l 20 -a b -nsr
> Vh.9"7`gN;;$kV*/LddE
> q);S;byf/._Z8;S1|>Kb
> 3<*FfS&Y&}wD17l[M?y{
> ```

Your thoughts and ideas are welcome.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#
# Random Password Generator
#
#

#set -x
COUNT=""
ALPHA=""
NUMERICAL=0
SPECIAL=0
STRING_LENGTH=""
RESHUF=0
# delimiters
nu="0-9"
al="a-z"
au="A-Z"
sc="!\"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_\`{|}~"

urandom_cat() {
# function generates random characters, delimiter gets send from function gen_char_pw
DELIMITER=$1
    cat /dev/urandom | env LC_CTYPE=C tr -cd $DELIMITER | head -c 1000
}

usage() {
cat << EOF

This script generates a number of passwords.

usage: $0 -c <number> -l <number> -a <option> -nsr

    c and l arguments are REQUIRED!

    at least one argument out of a, n and s is required

ARGUMENTS
   -h       Show this message
   -c number    Number of passwords to create
   -l number    Length of password
   -a u/l/b Use alphabet (upper-case/lower-case/both)
   -n       Use numbers
   -s       Use special characters
   -r       Reshuffle characters of final password (pretty much useless, but mehh, who cares?)


EOF
}

print_pw() {
# length of phrase gets checked 
# in case reshuffle option is ticked, phrase gets reshuffeld and printed out
# else phrase gets printed out. COUNT gets reduced by one
    if [[ "$(printf '%s' "$pw" | wc -m)" -eq $STRING_LENGTH ]] ; then
        if [[ $RESHUF -eq 1 ]] ; then 
            echo "$pw" | fold -w 1 | gshuf | tr -d "\\\r\n" ; echo
        else
            echo "$pw"
        fi
        COUNT=$(($COUNT-1)) 
    fi
}

gen_char_pw() {
# send delimiter to urandom_cat and fills characters into an array
# then random characters from the array get combined to a password
# trailing newline gets cut off and phrase gets cut to desired length
DELIMITER=$1    
    i=0
    for char in "$((urandom_cat $DELIMITER) | fold -w 1)" ; do
        CHARS[$i]=$char
    i=$(($i+1))
    done
    pw="$(gshuf -e "${CHARS[@]}" 2>/dev/null | tr -d "\\\r\n" | head -c $STRING_LENGTH)"
}

gen_pw() {
# lower-case letters
    if [[ $ALPHA == l && $NUMERICAL -eq 0 && $SPECIAL -eq 0 ]] ; then
        gen_char_pw $al
        case "$pw" in
        # contained characters get checked       
            *[a-z]*)
            print_pw
            ;;
        esac
# upper_case letters
    elif [[ $ALPHA == u && $NUMERICAL -eq 0 && $SPECIAL -eq 0 ]] ; then
        gen_char_pw $au 
        case "$pw" in 
            *[A-Z]*)
            print_pw
            ;;
        esac
# numbers
    elif [[ -z $ALPHA && $NUMERICAL -eq 1 && $SPECIAL -eq 0 ]] ; then
        gen_char_pw $nu 
        case "$pw" in 
            *[0-9]*)
            print_pw
            ;;
        esac
# special-characters
    elif [[ -z $ALPHA && $NUMERICAL -eq 0 && $SPECIAL -eq 1 ]] ; then
        gen_char_pw $sc 
        case "$pw" in 
            *[\!\"\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\-\.\/\:\;\<\=\>\?\@\[\\\]\^\_\`\{\|\}\~]*)
   print_pw
   ;;
  esac
# lower-case and upper-case letters
 elif [[ $ALPHA == b && $NUMERICAL -eq 0 && $SPECIAL -eq 0 ]] ; then
  gen_char_pw $al$au
  case "$pw" in 
   *[A-Z]*)
   case "$pw" in 
    *[a-z]*)
    print_pw
   esac
  esac
# lower-case letters and numbers
 elif [[ $ALPHA == l && $NUMERICAL -eq 1 && $SPECIAL -eq 0 ]] ; then
  gen_char_pw $al$nu
  case "$pw" in 
   *[a-z]*) 
   case "$pw" in 
    *[0-9]*)
    print_pw
    ;;
   esac
  esac
# upper-case letters and numbers
 elif [[ $ALPHA == u && $NUMERICAL -eq 1 && $SPECIAL -eq 0 ]] ; then
  gen_char_pw $au$nu
  case "$pw" in 
   *[A-Z]*) 
   case "$pw" in 
    *[0-9]*)
    print_pw
    ;;
   esac
  esac
# numbers and special-characters
 elif [[ -z $ALPHA && $NUMERICAL -eq 1 && $SPECIAL -eq 1 ]] ; then
  gen_char_pw $nu$sc
  case "$pw" in 
   *[0-9]*) 
   case "$pw" in 
    *[\!\"\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\-\.\/\:\;\<\=\>\?\@\[\\\]\^\_\`\{\|\}\~]*)
                print_pw
                ;;
            esac
        esac
# lower-case letters and special-characters
    elif [[ $ALPHA == l && $NUMERICAL -eq 0 && $SPECIAL -eq 1 ]] ; then
        gen_char_pw $al$sc  
        case "$pw" in 
            *[a-z]*)
            case "$pw" in 
                *[\!\"\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\-\.\/\:\;\<\=\>\?\@\[\\\]\^\_\`\{\|\}\~]*)
                    print_pw
            esac
        esac
# upper-case letters and special-characters
    elif [[ $ALPHA == u && $NUMERICAL -eq 0 && $SPECIAL -eq 1 ]] ; then
        gen_char_pw au$sc
        case "$pw" in 
            *[A-Z]*)
            case "$pw" in 
                *[\!\"\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\-\.\/\:\;\<\=\>\?\@\[\\\]\^\_\`\{\|\}\~]*)
    print_pw
   esac
  esac
# lower-case letters, numbers and special-characters
 elif [[ $ALPHA == l && $NUMERICAL -eq 1 && $SPECIAL -eq 1 ]] ; then
  gen_char_pw $al$nu$sc 
  case "$pw" in 
   *[0-9]*) 
   case "$pw" in 
    *[a-z]*)
    case "$pw" in 
     *[\!\"\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\-\.\/\:\;\<\=\>\?\@\[\\\]\^\_\`\{\|\}\~]*)
                    print_pw
                esac
            esac
        esac
# upper-case letters, numbers and special-characters
    elif [[ $ALPHA == u && $NUMERICAL -eq 1 && $SPECIAL -eq 1 ]] ; then
        gen_char_pw $au$nu$sc
        case "$pw" in 
            *[0-9]*) 
            case "$pw" in 
                *[A-Z]*)
                case "$pw" in 
                    *[\!\"\#\$\%\&\'\(\)\*\+\,\-\.\/\:\;\<\=\>\?\@\[\\\]\^\_\`\{\|\}\~]*)
                    print_pw
                esac
            esac
        esac
# lower-case and upper-case letters, numbers
    elif [[ $ALPHA == b && $NUMERICAL -eq 1 && $SPECIAL -eq 0 ]] ; then
        gen_char_pw $al$au$nu
        case "$pw" in 
            *[0-9]*) 
            case "$pw" in 
                *[A-Z]*)
                case "$pw" in 
                    *[a-z]*)
                    print_pw
                esac
            esac
        esac
# lower-case and upper-case letters, special-characters
    elif [[ $ALPHA == b && $NUMERICAL -eq 0 && $SPECIAL -eq 1 ]] ; then
        gen_char_pw $al$au$sc
        case "$pw" in 
            *[A-Z]*)
            case "$pw" in 
                *[a-z]*)
                case "$pw" in 
                    *[\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+\?\>\<\~\`\;\']*)
     print_pw
    esac
   esac
  esac
# lower-case and upper-case letters, numbers and special-characters
 elif [[ $ALPHA == b && $NUMERICAL -eq 1 && $SPECIAL -eq 1 ]] ; then
  gen_char_pw $al$au$nu$sc
  case "$pw" in 
   *[0-9]*) 
   case "$pw" in 
    *[A-Z]*)
    case "$pw" in 
     *[a-z]*)
     case "$pw" in 
      *[\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\+\?\>\<\~\`\;\']*)
                        print_pw
                    esac
                esac
            esac
        esac
    fi
}

while getopts c:a:l:nshr opt ; do
    case "$opt" in
    c)  COUNT="$2" ;;
    l)  STRING_LENGTH="$4" ;;
    a)  ALPHA="$6" ;;
    n)  NUMERICAL=1 ;;  
    s)  SPECIAL=1 ;;
    r)  RESHUF=1 ;;
    --) usage
        exit 1 ;;
    h)  usage
        exit 1 ;;
    *)  usage
        exit 1 ;;
    esac
done

if [[ -z $COUNT ]] || [[ -z $STRING_LENGTH ]] ; then
    usage
    exit 1
elif [[ -z $ALPHA ]] && [[ $NUMERICAL -eq 0 ]] && [[ $SPECIAL -eq 0 ]] ; then
    usage
    exit 1
fi

while [ $COUNT -gt 0 ]; do
    gen_pw
done
exit 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems all clean and proper.

But.

The function `gen_pw()` is a bit, how shall I put it, longwinded.

You can use variables in `sed`, too, so something like (in one line for easy C&P)

```
r1="A-Z"; r2="0-9"; r3="" ; cat /dev/urandom | tr -cd '[:graph:]' | head -c 1000| sed -e "s/[^$r1$r2$r3]//g" | head -c 10
```

can be done easily

If you base your program on it you can just fill the variables with the chosen characters.

```
r1="";
r2="";
r3="";
r4="";
if   [[ $NUMERICAL -eq 1 ]] ; then
   r1 = $nu;
elif [[ $ALPHA == l ]] || [[ $ALPHA == b ]] ; then
   r2 = $al;
elif [[ $ALPHA == u ]] || [[ $ALPHA == b ]] ; then
   r3 = $au;
elif [[ $SPECIAL -eq 1 ]] ; then
   r4 = $sc;
endif
```

(above is not tested, just to show what I meant)
Then you run the one-liner from the top

```
cat /dev/urandom  | tr -cd '[:graph:]' | head -c 1000| sed -e "s/[^$r1$r2$r3$r4]//g" | head -c $STRING_LENGTH
```

It is a bit shorter, I think.

You still need to check if the input from the user makes sense, if the output is actually `$STRING_LENGTH` long (you are using a random source!) and all of the rest, but you already have most, if not all of it. And check if `tr -cd '[:graph:]'` doesn't let pass too much or too little.